# How can i pick a random character from char[]

Tags: java

**How can i pick a random char from azL and then put it in another list?**

char[] azL = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o',
            'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_random_w);
    initializeValues();

    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int Plength = 6;
            for (int x = 0;x < Plength;x++){

            }
           // textV.setText();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Look for `Random` class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-to-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random number with

```
int randomIndex = (int)(Math.random()*list.size());
```

Then you can pick that random element and add it to a new List with

```
newList.add(list.get(randomIndex));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Random class to generate a random integer in the required range, i.e. 0 to azl.length. Then get the element at the random index from the array and put it in the other list.

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(azl.length);    // [0, azl.length-1]
otherList.add(azl[randomIndex]);
```